undetected chrome driver- mismatch between chromedriver and chrome version
im running the following code using undetected_chromedriver:
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

driver = uc.Chrome()

im getting the following error:

selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message:
session not created: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:42071 from
session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome
version 131 Current browser version is 130.0.6723.116

My google chrome version is (Google Chrome 131.0.6778.69)
My chrome driver version is (ChromeDriver 131.0.6778.69)
Despite the fact that both Chrome and ChromeDriver versions match, I am still encountering a version mismatch error.
Additionally, when executing the script, there is a 50% chance that the code will run successfully without triggering the above error.
Any ideas?

Found solution by adding path of chrome to the chrome options. (using options.binary_location)
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)

For above to work, chrome and chromedriver have to have matching versions.

You can also turn off version checking by setting environment variable of "webdriver.chrome.disableBuildCheck" : "true"

Try the below:
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

driver = uc.Chrome(version_main=130)

Argument version_main=130 forces uc to use driver version 130, rather than the available latest version(which is 131).

this works, however im facing random connection interruptions in selenium which I think is due to the version mismatch anyhow i found a solution which i will post
